# Scala, how to set up a node class?

Tags: scala

Is there a resource for setting up a generic class in Scala? I am trying to make a segment tree where the node class contains a pointer to a left node, a pointer to a right node, and the value of the sum (and some other stuff but I think if I can get this working I can do the rest myself).

Is there a "class" type of specification because right now all I can think of doing is

```
sealed trait Tree
case class Node(var left: Tree, var right: Tree, var value: Int) extends Tree
case object EmptyNode extends Tree
```

But I don't know if this encapsulates things like methods and whatever, or if I need to just make an "external" function for things like building the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algebraic data types break encapsulation by exposing the internal representation of the type publicly. When you take a functional programming point of view with regards to your design, then mutable state is not something that is a concern normally. Therefore, exposing the internal representation is not really a big deal as it is in OOP.

The design below shows how to achieve parametric polymorphism:

```
sealed trait Tree[+A]
case class Leaf[A] (value : A) extends Tree[A]
case class Branch[A](left : Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]

object Tree{
  // put your functions that operate on Trees here.
}
```

Comment: I am a little confused -- is the code you posted the "correct" way or is mine also a valid way about it, or is mine totally wrong somehow?

Comment: I just gave you another example. It differs from yours in that it only stores data at the leaf level, whereas yours does so at each node. However, mine is polymorphic whereas yours in monomorphic. In your post you wanted a generic type which why I posted my example. I think your confusion was also about where to place functions that operate on trees. As you can see in my example, they are typically located in the companion object.

Comment: What do you mean polymorphic vs monomorphic? Like yours can be re-used in various contexts whereas mine is rather fixed?

Comment: Yours is "fixed" in the sense that you can only take integers as values to store in the node. The above example will take any type. So a Tree[String], Tree[Double] etc...

Comment: Gotcha. Also why do I see "leaf" implementations often when it comes to Scala? Is there a reason why stuff gets stored as "leaves" rather than as a data element of a node?

Comment: A leaf is just another node. Nothing special.

Comment: Encapsulation and information hiding aren't the same. Just because the tree exposes its internals doesn't mean it breaks encapsulation. Also, whether you only store data in your leaves or in every node depends on what you want to use your tree for.